# mezzanine on azure - hebrew urls returns 404

Tags: django, azure, mezzanine

When I run the site local on django dev server all works just fine.
Whaen I publish the site to azure all the urls (mezzanine pages) that contains hebrew return django 404 error.

other django sites (non mezzanine ) works just fine on azure)

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use hebrew in your urls. I use hebrew in my django projects too, but never in the urls. It's a world of headaches you can easily avoid